# Javascript string splits by space when appending as class attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to append class to an `<a>` element dynamically as follows.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var class = "abc def ghi";
  var url = "something";
  var innerText = "some random text";

  var innerLink = "<a href=" + url + "><i data-name=" + class + " class=" + class + "></i><span>" + innerText + "</span></a>";

  $("#test").append(innerLink);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">

</div>
```

The string class can have spaces in between. When the append happens the resulting string looks like `<a href="something"><i data-name="abc" def ghi class="abc"></i><span>some random text</span></a>`

(inspect element in the result to see it) .

But what i'm expecting is `<a href="something"><i data-name="abc def ghi" class="abc def ghi"></i><span>some random text</span></a>`

What is wrong with the code ?

Comment: Not related to your question, but you should not use `class` as a variable name, for it is a reserved keyword.

Comment: Yes , I was trying to create a quick working sample.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to have another wrapper quotes if the value is space  separated:

```
class='" + class + "'></i><span>" +
//    ^             ^  ------check this
```

---

```
var innerLink = "<a href='" + url 
                + "'><i data-name='" + class + "' class='" + class + "'></i><span>" + 
innerText + "</span></a>"; //-----^-------------^-------^-------------^
```

Comment: Wouldn't the plus signs be added to the string and end up in the innerlink?
Seems that the extra quotes need to be added to the class string itself.

var class = "'abc def ghi'";

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the internal quotes around the class and name attributes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var class = "abc def ghi";
  var url = "something";
  var innerText = "some random text";

  var innerLink = "<a href=" + url + "><i data-name='" + class + "' class='" + class + "'></i><span>" + innerText + "</span></a>";

  $("#test").append(innerLink);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">

</div>
```